# newtab content cannot be alter using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to alter the content of my newtab using javascript. In my manifest.json I have this

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab": "index.html"
   }
```

then in my index.html I have

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>hello world</h1>
</body>
```

then in my script.js I do `$('h1').remove()` nothing triggered. Why? When I try to do `console.log($)` it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs as soon as Chrome inserts the `<script>` tag into the DOM tree.

By the time that happens, `<h1>` is not there *yet*.

There are two solutions; one is to simply move the `<script>` tag below the nodes you refer to.

The other, preferable solution is to use an event that says "okay, DOM tree is complete, you can work with nodes now". Using jQuery, it will be [the `ready` event](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* your code here */
});
```

Or, shortened,

```
$(function() {
  /* your code here */
});
```